# cpufreq is missing from /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0

Tags: cpu

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0# ls
cache        crash_notes_size  firmware_node  microcode  power      topology
crash_notes  driver            hotplug        node0      subsystem  uevent
```

I searched for cpuinfo_cur_freq not found & cpuinfo_cur_freq does not exist - nothing

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MHz"
cpu MHz     : 3269.310
cpu MHz     : 3291.034
cpu MHz     : 3094.668
cpu MHz     : 2641.935
```

so cpus are at different speeds

EDIT:

```
description: CPU
          product: AMD Ryzen 3 1200 Quad-Core Processor
cpufreq-info --driver gives no output
uname -a Linux ub7 5.8.0-44-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 9 06:29:41 UTC 021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
frequency scaling is enabled in BIOS = Yes
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10 Release:   20.10
```

so it looks like no CPU frequency scaling driver is Installed
Do I need a driver as it looks like the CPU frequency are changing without a driver

Comment: You have not told us what processor make and model, Ubuntu version, if frequency scaling is enabled in BIOS, which CPU frequency scaling driver and governor you are using, if any.... So yes, those directories might not exist for your use case. The CPU frequencies listed are an average of the active time for that CPU over the last sampling time, and typically are not the same, even if the CPUs are driven from one common PLL (phase locked loop).

Comment: description: CPU
          product: AMD Ryzen 3 1200 Quad-Core Processor

Comment: Do I need a driver - more details in Answer

Comment: I moved the new content to your question. you can delete the answer. The appropriate driver should have loaded by itself. Perhaps it uses `devfreq`, I don't know.

Comment: as far as I can determine, it should be using the `acpi-cpufreq` CPU frequency scaling driver. I don't know why it isn't.

Comment: messages ... Firmware Bug ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer mem 0xdd4a4000-oxdd4a4fff flags ox200 vs dd4a4000 4000 ...

dbus-service:12 KillMode=none ...
plymouth-start.service KillMode=none

Comment: lightdm.service failed with exit-code